# file column compare awk (gawk) with refinment

Tags: awk

From my Two input files:
(file1.txt)

```
a   11-23
b   33-39
c   40-45
d   46-58
```

& (file2.txt)

```
33-39
40-42
43-47
51-52
```

I need to match the file2 values from second column of file1 (with check for intermediate ranges) and want the output to be like:

```
b   33-39
c   40-42, 43-45
d   46-47, 51-52
```

Note that 'd 46-47, 51-52' appear in the last line as 43-47 range in file2 falls under c and d.

Stack overflow user karakfa, gracefully suggests a way like:

```
$ join -j 99 file1 file2 | 
  awk '$2==$3{print $1,$2; next} {split($2,a,"-"); split($3,b,"-")}
   a[1]>=b[1] && a[2]<=b[2] || a[1]<=b[1] && a[2]>=b[2] {print $1,$2",",$3}'
```

it gives the output as:

```
b 33-39
c 40-45, 40-42
d 46-58, 51-52
```

However, the entire range values of 'c 40-45' and 'd 46-58' were not the range I want, and also I need it to be GNU Awk compatible to run on my windows machine.

Comment: I doubt `awk` is best for the job here..

Comment: And what did you try yourself? Did you look at the awk documentation and did you understand how the arrays work, how to create loops over arrays, how to work on several files... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution in [TXR](http://www.nongnu.org/txr):

```
@(do
   (defstruct interval nil
     lo hi

     (:postinit (self)
       (unless (< self.lo self.hi)
         (swap self.lo self.hi)))

     (:method print (self stream)
       (put-string `@{self.lo}-@{self.hi}` stream))

     (:method intersects (self other)
       (and (>= self.hi other.lo)
            (<= self.lo other.hi)))

     (:method clip (self other)
       (new interval
            lo (max self.lo other.lo)
            hi (min self.hi other.hi))))

   (defstruct tabentry nil
     label
     interval
     matches

     (:method insert (self other)
       (when self.interval.(intersects other)
         (push self.interval.(clip other) self.matches)))))
@(next "file1.txt")
@(collect :vars (tab))
@label @lo-@hi
@  (bind tab @(new tabentry
                   label label
                   interval (new interval
                                 lo (int-str lo)
                                 hi (int-str hi))))
@(end)
@(next "file2.txt")
@(repeat)
@lo-@hi
@  (do
     (let ((iv (new interval
                    lo (int-str lo)
                    hi (int-str hi))))
       (each ((te tab))
         te.(insert iv))))
@(end)
@(do (each ((te tab))
       (when te.matches
         (put-line `@{te.label} @{(reverse te.matches) ", "}`))))
```

Run:

```
$ txr tab-range.txr 
b 33-39
c 40-42, 43-45
d 46-47, 51-52
```